# Find direction in which this derivative has a maximum value

Tags: calculus, vectors

The function $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + xyz + y^2$

---

**I found the directional derivative:**

$\vec a$ = $(1,2,2)$ at point $(1,1,1)$

$dx f$ = $2x + yz   =  2(1) + (1)(1) = 3$

$dy f$ = $2y + xz = 2(1) + (1)(1) = 3$

$dz f$ = $xy = (1)(1) = 1$

$Duf = <3,3,1>$

---

$\vec a$ = $(1,2,2)$ =

$\vec a*$Duf = $\frac{1,2,2}{3}\ * <3,1,1>$

**= $\frac 3{11}$**

---

**Now I have to find the direction in which this derivative has a maximum value**

I thought it was just Dmax

$DuF(1,1,1) = |f(1,1,1)| = \sqrt{3^2+3^2+1^2} = \ \sqrt{19} $

but this wasn't the correct answer, not sure how to finish this question.

Comment: Hint: when does the dot product of fixed-length vectors achieve its maximum value?

Comment: @amd - so the direction would just be the vector <3,3,1>?

Comment: That’s right. The gradient points in the direction of maximum change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the maximum value of the directional derivative, but you were being asked to find the direction in which this occurs. Since $D_uf=\nabla f\cdot u$, this occurs when the two vectors point in the same direction. In other words, the gradient of the function points in the direction of maximum change.